# Python: is it possible to compare function import origin?

Tags: python

I have 4 python files, the first two is the function itself, the second is functions dictionary, and the third is kind of a 'definition' parser

#### function_1

```
def increment(obj):
  return obj+1
#another function
```

#### function_2

```
def decrement(obj):
  return obj-1
#another function
```

#### function_dictionary

```
import fucntion1
import function2
FUNC_DICT = {
  'increment': function1.increment,
  'decrement': function2.decrement,
  #another function
}
```

#### definition_parser

```
from function_dictionary import FUNC_DICT
def get_definition():
  result = {}
  for key, value in FUNC_DICT.items():
    #check if value is from function_1 or function_2
    #result[key] = 'function_1' or 'function_2', depends on its origin
return result
```

is it possible to compare function import? I tried it with `is_in_function_1 = value is in function_1`, doesn't work.

if it is not, what are the way around without much repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the module of functions via the `__module__` property.

```
from function_dictionary import FUNC_DICT
def get_definition():
  result = {}
  for key, value in FUNC_DICT.items():
    result[key] = value.__module__
return result
```

The output would look like the following:

```
{
  'increment': 'function_1',
  'decrement': 'function_2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the inspect module like so:

```
import inspect

print(inspect.getmodule(SequenceMatcher))
```

for example, if I inspect SequenceMatcher, the output is:

```
<module 'difflib' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\difflib.py'>
```

So to compare the origin of two functions, you could simply do this:

```
if inspect.getmodule(increment) == inspect.getmodule(decrement): 
    do stuff
```